# Bind keys to copy-mode in tmux: overriding and list of commands available

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I use PgUp and PgDown, without modifiers, to switch windows in tmux:

```
bind -n PageUp previous-window
bind -n PageDown next-window
```

The problem I have is that in copy-mode those bindings are active, and want to use those keys for scrolling commands.  So I try things like

```
set -g mode-keys emacs
bind-key -t emacs-copy PageUp scroll-up
bind-key -t emacs-copy PageDown scroll-down
bind-key -n -t emacs-copy PageUp scroll-up
bind-key -n -t emacs-copy PageDown scroll-down
```

for overriding this.  That does not work; PageUp and PageDown still cycle between windows.

How can I override my bindings when I enter in copy-mode?

I am using tmux 1.6 (I am new to tmux, btw; I am trying to migrate to it after years of using screen)

Comment: There is ["Fundamental change to how copy mode key bindings work"](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/76d6d3641f271be1756e41494960d96714e7ee58) starting from tmux 2.5